# If f is cont. on [a,b]. then $\exists$ c $\in$ [a,b] such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt = f(c)(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

If f is cont. on [a,b]. then $\exists$ c $\in$ [a,b] such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt = f(c)(b-a).$ Give an example to show that this is not true if f is not continuous but merely integrable.

Could anyone tell me the idea to solve this question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m$ and $M$ are the minimum and maximum vaues of $f$ then $m \leq \frac { \int_a^{b} f(x)\, dx} {b-a} \leq M$. Since $f$ attains the values $m$ and $M$ it attains every value inbetween (by IVP). Hence there exists $c$ such that $\int_a^{b} f(x)\, dx=f(c)$. For a counterexample take $f(x)=-1$ for $-1\leq x \leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: The first statement by the mean value theorem ..... correct?

Comment: @hopefully You can get it from MVT but you can also prove it from the definition of Riemann integral.

Comment: How to prove that it is wrong for your counter example Kavi, how to prove that there is no such c?

Comment: @hopefully The integral is $0$ and $f(c)$ is not $0$ for any $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ has a minimum and a maximum on $[a, b]$ if it's continuous. For $f$ not continuous, the simplest non-continuous function you can think of probably works.